# Drag and Drop Sort Custom Entities

Tags: forms, 8, entities, ajax

I am looking for a simple way to sort my custom entities through a drag and drop interface and display them in the custom order in my views.

The best way would probably be to add a weight basefield to the entity type and let the drag and drop interface change the weight on each entity through ajax. Are there any examples on how to do that?

Comment: The Weight module for D8 has a release and can do what you ask at a basic level. I create an admin view that lets you order the entities as drag and drop, and then use other views to display it. Only drawback is the weight is stored on the entity, not the view, so its a not a localized value.

Answer (score 1):

You can created an administration page views with you custom entities and to sort it you can use use the [DraggableViews](https://www.drupal.org/project/draggableviews) module. You would have to create another view to display your entities.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't see any D8 support. Is there any alpha/beta repository?

Comment: No yet, you can open an issue at their issue queue asking about it.